# Custom protocol in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How can you implement a custom protocol in OpenLayers? What are the specific methods that you need to override in OpenLayers.Protocol to make it work?

I tried to implement just the read method, but specifying the protocol to a Vector layer had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was somewhere else. Implementing the read method is enough, but you need to call the callback method passed as an argument.